# How to align button on the left, and logo in the center on the same row using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have this code

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-default mainbutton pull-left">Back to Main Menu</a>
    <img class="center-block" src="logo.png" />
</div>
```

It appears that the logo image is off-centered because it only takes the margin measurement after the button. How can I ensure that the button is aligned to the center?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the button and the image in two different columns
Just like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    //your button code
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    //your image code
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    //some other stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a break in between like:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-default mainbutton pull-left">Back to Main Menu</a>
    <br/>
    <img class="center-block" src="logo.png" />
</div>
```

After ensuring your image is positioned below your button, you should be able to follow the instructions in  [How to vertically align an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) if you need help aligning content inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into 3 equal columns to make it easier.
Then you can use text-center:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Back to Main Menu</a>  
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <img src="logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```